# Multiprocessing the while-loop in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, multiprocessing

I'm currently trying to increase the speed of which my programm is processing videos via cv2 (it mainly searches for circles and counts them). I stumbled upon the multiprocessing topic and found out about the Pool object, yet even after reading the document, I still have no clue where to put Pool in my code.
The second class creates an UI in which my processed video is displayed inside a QLabel.

```
import...
globals.global_vars()

''' Video processing class '''
class Thread(QThread):
    changePixmap = pyqtSignal(QImage)

    def run(self):
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(globals.VideoFile)
        globals.frame_count = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

        while True:
            try:
                cv2.waitKey(globals.Speed)
                ret, frame = cap.read()

                ''' hsv parameter for filter + apply them via mask '''
                hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
                lower_blue = np.array([globals.L_H, globals.L_S, globals.L_V])
                upper_blue = np.array([globals.U_H, globals.U_S, globals.U_V])
                mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
                res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)
                blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(res, (15, 15), 0)
                blur = cv2.rectangle(blur, (globals.Left, globals.Upper), (globals.Right, globals.Under), (0, 0, 255), 2)

                ''' Search cirlce on croped blur-window '''
                img = cv2.medianBlur(blur, 15)
                imgg = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
                circles = cv2.HoughCircles(imgg, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 30, param1=10, param2=10, minRadius=6,
                                           maxRadius=11)
                all_circles_blured = np.uint16(np.around(circles))

                ''' draw circle on blur-window '''
                for i in all_circles_blured[0, :]:
                    cv2.circle(blur, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 1)
                [...]

                ''' Send/Display frame as QImage to QLabel'''
                h, w, ch = blur.shape
                bytesPerLine = ch * w
                convertToFormat = QImage(blur.data, w, h, bytesPerLine, QImage.Format_RGB888)
                convertToFormat = convertToFormat.rgbSwapped()
                m = convertToFormat.scaled(640, 480, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
                self.changePixmap.emit(m)

            except ValueError:
                print("TypeError: No circle found")

''' UI class '''
class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(1000, 800)
        self.setWindowTitle("MainWindow")
        self.initUI()

    def setImage(self, image):
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(image))


    def initUI(self):
        [...]
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 130, 320, 240))
        [...]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: you have to create Pool before `while` loop and use it inside `while` loop. But I don't know how you want to process and display at the same time. if you will send frames to multiprocesses then you will have to control which frame display before other frames - and if processes may run with different speed then some frames will have to wait for other frames. And you will need extra time to send frame from main process to other process and send it back to main process to display.

Comment: Seams like it wouldn't be worth using pool in this case.... How about creating 4 QLabels and processing 4 videos at once uning pool(4)? Would that be possible and 4x more time-saving?

Comment: do you have to display it ? Maybe it will work faster if you will not display it - or display only some frame - ie. every 4 frames.

Comment: it doesn't speed up, if I don't display it. I am pretty sure the most time/resource consuming part is the frame processing.